# Limit of variance of maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: random-variables, maximum-likelihood

Le $X_1, \ldots,X_n$  be samples of  $\mathcal{N}_1(\mu,1)$ and $Y_n$'s are independent of $X_1, \ldots,X_n$ s.t.
$$\Pr(Y_n=1)=n^{-2}=1−\Pr(Y_n=0)$$

1. Let $L$ be MLE of $\mu$ by $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, and put $Z_n=(1−Y_n)L+\sqrt{n} Y_n$. What is 
   $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\operatorname{Var}(\sqrt{n}(Z_n−\mu))?$$

So far I calculated the following:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(\sqrt{n}((1-Y_n)L+\sqrt{n}Y_n-\mu)) & = \operatorname{Var}(\sqrt{n}(L-\mu) + nY_n -\sqrt{n}Y_nL) \\
&= \operatorname{Var}(\sqrt{n}(L-\mu)) + n^2\operatorname{Var}(Y_n) - \operatorname{Var}(\sqrt{n}L)Var(Y_n) 
\end{align}

Is that mathematically correct? Furthermore, I calculated $\operatorname{Var}(Y_n)$ which should be
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y_n) = \mathbb{E}[Y_n^2]- \mathbb{E}[Y_N]^2 = \dfrac{n^2-1}{n^4}$$

So can I say the limit equals to $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\operatorname{Var}(\sqrt{n}(Z_n−\mu)) = 1 + 1 = 2?$$

Thank you very much in advance for helping me.

Comment: The answer is given by the limit of the Cramer Rao lower bound